# how to export data to csv using loops in python

Tags: python, csv

That's the updated version of my previous answer.
I am not familiar with how to export the list to the `csv` in a loop.

Here is code for one list:

```
import csv
X = ([1,2,3],[7,8,9])
Y = ([4,5,6],[3,4,5])
for x in range(0,2,1):
    csvfile = "C:/Temp/aaa.csv"
    with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
        for val in x[0]:
            writer.writerow([val])
```

I want to export the result in the csv loop by loop, e.g, when `x=0`, we write the first two columns`(x0,y0)` and when `x=2`, we add the next two columns`(x2,y2)` in the same CSV, etc. And here is the final result showed in the CSV:

[image]

Comment: What is you question? The csv screenshot- is this the desired result, or the current one?

Comment: @Shir i only know how to write one column, but don't know how to add columns loop by loop

Comment: You may want to look into the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import csv
X = ([1,2,3],[7,8,9])
Y = ([4,5,6],[3,4,5])

csvfile = "C:/tmp/aaa.csv"
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,2):
        l.append([])
        l.append([])
        l[2*i]=["x= "+str(i),"x"]+X[i]
        l[2*i+1]=["","y"]+Y[i]

    l_by_rows=zip(*l)
    writer.writerows(l_by_rows)
```

I write the results to `l` by columns, than use `zip` to transform it to rows, and write it to the csv.

The result:

[image]

Comment: why do you need `l.append([]) l.append([])`?

Comment: I append two columns for every x (one for X and one for Y). Maybe there is a more elegant way to append two elements, this was what came out to my head in this moment :)

Comment: It works, thx! By the way, if k=zip(a,b), and how to add c to k to get the result zip(a,b,c)?